# Swift: how to use Main.storyboard for portrait and Main_landscape.storyboard for landscape automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, landscape-portrait

I am developing a iPhone app and this app has 2 different design for portrait and landscape mode.
There are several storyboards in this app, and all view controllers in other storyboards can be made in a storyboard for portrait and landscape using constraints.
But only Main storyboard should be made for portrait and landscape for each because designs are fully different.
There are 3 view controllers in Main storyboard.

How can I do this?

Comment: How different are the designs? You might possibly want to look into `UISplitViewController`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller.
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/
This might be helpful